# hasMany relationship is null

Tags: php, laravel-5, has-many

I'm new to Laravel 5.0.
I'm trying to make a hasmany relationship between my two models, `User` and `Device`.
If in tinker  I do `App\user::first()->device` the result is `null`

I populated the users and devices tables with some dummy data and the single `find()` work.
I searched on StackOverflow but I could't find out a solution

Here's my `users table`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

my `devices table`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('devices', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->double('lat', 15, 8);
        $table->double('lon', 15, 8);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and my function in the `User Model`

```
public function device()
{
return  $this->hasMany('App\Device');
}
```

Thank you all

Comment: Have you tried `App\User::device()->first()` ?

Comment: it says:`Non-static method App\User::device() should not be called statically on line 1` even if I declare device() as static

Comment: And what `App\user::first()` returns? A User model?

Comment: the first user entry `<App\User #000000000dcc4d60000000005aa5b898> {
       id: 1,
       name: "Leon",
       email: "asd@asd.com",
       created_at: "2017-04-20 18:44:59",
       updated_at: "2017-05-10 16:38:26"
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was right, I found out sometimes tinker needs to be rebooted after the changes in the code